# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Last[Int32]

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

what's the problem with this ?

```
int folderid = (from p in db.folder where p.isDefault == true select p.id).Last();
```

i get this error

```
   LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Last[Int32]
    (System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be 
translated into a store expression.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linq can not translate the `Last()` to any valid sql statment. So my suggestion would be to `orderby decending` and `Take(1)`

Maybe something like this:

```
int? folderid =(
        from p in db.folder 
        where p.isDefault == true 
        orderby p.id descending
        select p.id
    ).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

I don't know which to take so you might have to change the `orderby p.id descending` to something that suites you.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` would not blow this up if the collection is empty. But still +1 from me, this is the correct approach.

Comment: Don't you think `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()` would be more intuitive here?

Comment: if the collection be empty , exception will throw . 
is it true ?

Comment: Yeah I think `Single()` if he expects a value. If it could be null then i would recommend `SingleOrDefault()`. Thanks for point it out.