# Get the last id using Entity Famework and Linq

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, linq

Hi I'm making a CRUD using Asp.net. I'm trying to get the last id of a table with Linq but I receive the next error:

System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 LastInt32' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

I'm trying with this form:

```
public ActionResult getLastId()
{
var id = db.DatesReports.Select(x => x.idReport).Last();
return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm making something like this on the frontend:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("getLastId", "Home")', function (data) {
alert(parseInt(data.data));
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Last\[Int32\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967990/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-lastint32)

Comment: I made a test with:

var id = db.DatesReports.Select(x => x.idReport).First();

And it work, I don't understand why when i use .Last() it dosen't work

Comment: @JohnatanDeLeon  please see the link that Prolog posted . Linq cannot be able to translate this you have to order  by descending and have to get  the first one
You have to do  this  db.DatesReports.Select(x => x.idReport).OrderByDescending ().First();

Comment: @Bosco Why would Last not work on a list with one element? Last time I tried it was working.

Comment: I made this and it worked:
var id = db.DatesReports.OrderByDescending(x => x.idReport).Select(x => x.idReport).FirstOrDefault();

Thank you for your help!